# Internal processes of the apt stage "Preparing to unpack"

Tags: apt

What happens during the "Preparing to unpack" **apt** phase? Why is this message so important to show?

Comment: `.deb` files (which is what's being "unpacked") can have difficulties, ranging from a corrupt archive to insufficient disk space. The "``preparing to unpack`" message gives context to any error messages that may follow.